# Blur an image on MouseClick in C#

Tags: c#, forms, mouseevent, mouse, blur

So I have this form with a picturebox on it, the idea is to blur the image just around the cursor when i click it. Any ideas?

It worked on another pc when it just had to blur the whole image, and all I added was the mouse location stuff and it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap newBitmap;
    Image file;
    int blurAmount = 5 ;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            newBitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            pictureBox1.Image=file;
        }

    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int x = e.Location.X-25; x < e.Location.X+25; x++)
            {
                for (int y =e.Location.Y-25; y < e.Location.Y+25; y++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Color prevX = newBitmap.GetPixel(x - blurAmount, y);
                        Color nextX = newBitmap.GetPixel(x + blurAmount, y);
                        Color prevY = newBitmap.GetPixel(x, y - blurAmount);
                        Color nextY = newBitmap.GetPixel(x, y + blurAmount);

                        int avgR = (int)((prevX.R + nextX.R + prevY.R + nextY.R) / 4);
                        int avgG = (int)((prevX.G + nextX.G + prevY.G + nextY.G) / 4);
                        int avgB = (int)((prevX.B + nextX.B + prevY.B + nextY.B) / 4);

                        newBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(avgR, avgG, avgB));
                    }
                    catch (Exception) {}
                }
            }
           pictureBox1.Image = newBitmap;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set a click event for a **pictureBox** and works fine

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap newBitmap;
    Image file;
    int blurAmount = 5;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Occurs when the pictureBox1 control is clicked.
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            newBitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            pictureBox1.Image = file;
        }

    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        Point coordinates = me.Location;

        for (int x = me.Location.X - 25; x < me.Location.X + 25; x++)
        {
            for (int y = me.Location.Y - 25; y < me.Location.Y + 25; y++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Color prevX = newBitmap.GetPixel(x - blurAmount, y);
                    Color nextX = newBitmap.GetPixel(x + blurAmount, y);
                    Color prevY = newBitmap.GetPixel(x, y - blurAmount);
                    Color nextY = newBitmap.GetPixel(x, y + blurAmount);

                    int avgR = (int)((prevX.R + nextX.R + prevY.R + nextY.R) / 4);
                    int avgG = (int)((prevX.G + nextX.G + prevY.G + nextY.G) / 4);
                    int avgB = (int)((prevX.B + nextX.B + prevY.B + nextY.B) / 4);

                    newBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(avgR, avgG, avgB));
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = newBitmap;
    }
}
```